# Focus does not move to next new row in grid view when press tab key

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, tabs, row

I have designed a wpf page. But I not able to set Proper Tab Navigation on Grid view. Controls (grid view) on the page are not following tab index. Page contain Grid and Save,Cancel button.

There is a gridview. This grid has rows and columns. Each row contains 2 autocompletebox and 6 textboxes. When first i enter the value on the first autocompletebox,then enter tab it move to next box and so on. I enter the value in last text box and press enter button, then a new row will be formed in the grid. Then i press the tab it focus move on the outside button(Save button). I want to move the focus on the next box( first autocomplete box,not on the save button) in the second row in the grid.Pls help...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried to set/ correct the `Control.TabIndex` properties of the freshly added item?
See [MSDN - Control.TabIndex Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.tabindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) .

Maybe you like to do this using the `AddingNewItem` event in order to manipulate added items before they are displayed.
See [MSDN - DataGrid.AddingNewItem Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.addingnewitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).